# Php how to create custom array using 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need some help on below array formation. I want to create a custom array using 2 arrays.

This is my first array :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26
            [1] => 0.0000000000000000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => 0.0000000000000000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [1] => 0.0000000000000000
        )
)
```

This is my second array :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26
        )
)
```

I want final array as below. Can someone please suggest how to form this array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26
            [1] => 0.0000000000000000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [1] => 0.0000000000000000
        )
)
```

I have used below but I want it without foreach.

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($secondArray as $key => $value) {
    $key = array_search($value[0], array_column($firstArray, 0));
    $finalArray[] = $firstArray[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter):

```
$finalArray = array_filter($firstArray, 
    fn($item) => in_array($item[0], array_column($secondArray, 0))
);
```

It could be more efficiant to compute allowed values first:

```
$allowedValues = array_column($secondArray, 0);
$finalArray = array_filter($firstArray, fn($item) => in_array($item[0], $allowedValues));
```

Before PHP 7.4, you have to use `use()` to pass variable to the anonymous function:

```
$finalArray = array_filter($firstArray, 
    function($item) use($secondArray) { 
        return in_array($item[0], array_column($secondArray, 0)); 
    }
);
```

Comment: Does it answer your question?